# How to clear FxCop warnings while using string.Format(......) in UWP?

Tags: uwp, fxcop, string.format

I have used the below code in my project.While using this FxCop warning CA1305 occurs.

```
string endtime = string.Format("{0:0000}{1:00}{2:00}T{3:00}{4:00}{5:00}", SchAppointment.EndTime.Year,
                                               SchAppointment.EndTime.Month, SchAppointment.EndTime.Day,
                                               SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Hours,
                                               SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Minutes,
                                               SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
```

how can i clear this warning from my project?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue. What is your `SchAppointment.EndTime`? Without a complete sample, we can't know why you have warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should like this:

```
string endtime = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    "{0:0000}{1:00}{2:00}T{3:00}{4:00}{5:00}",
    SchAppointment.EndTime.Year,
    SchAppointment.EndTime.Month,
    SchAppointment.EndTime.Day,
    SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Hours,
    SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Minutes,
    SchAppointment.EndTime.TimeOfDay.Seconds);
```

This gives the Format method the information to format the numbers.